# Use htaccess to add file extensions to links but omit folders

Tags: php, .htaccess

In my main navigation I have links to each static page of the website. Each webpage file has a .php extension and I have removed the .php extension from all the links and the following entry in my htaccess file adds them.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Ive just tried to install a WordPress blog in a subfolder /demo and when I try to visit the directory domain.com/demo I get a 404 and the url shows as domain.com/demo.php

How can I get the htaccess to omit folders from its rewrite rule?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/demo [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: This would only work on /demo. How do I apply this rule to any folder name?

Comment: Change the new line with `%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d`

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. You need to check in the Apache config file between these tags

```
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

that `AllowOverride` is set to `All`.